# How can I call a function when the AlertDialog is dismissed?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I created an AlertDialog with a ListView. When the AlertDialog is created it starts also scanning for BLE devices. When the user clicks on one of the items the `scanLeDevice` function is called and this will stop further scanning. I would like to know how can I call this function when I click outside the AlertDialog?

```
public class BLEScan extends AlertDialog {
....
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

...
bleList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            BLEScan.this.scanLeDevice(false);
            selectedBluetoothDevice =(BluetoothDevice) (bleList.getItemAtPosition(i));
            BLEScan.this.dismiss();
        }
    });
```

Comment: see this : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setOnDismissListener(android.content.DialogInterface.OnDismissListener)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set an `OnDismissListener` via `setOnDismissListener()`

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

You can **override** the `onDismiss`  method in the `DialogFragment`, that is been called when the dialog gets dismissed.

Hope, This may help you!